# Closures and for loops in Ruby

Tags: ruby, closures

I'm kind of new to Ruby and some of the closure logic has me a confused. Consider this code:

```
array = []
for i in (1..5)
  array << lambda {i}
end
array.map{|f| f.call} # => [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

This makes sense to me because i is bound outside the loop, so the same variable is captured by each trip through the loop. It also makes sense to me that using an each block can fix this:

```
array = []
(1..5).each{|i|  array << lambda {i}}
array.map{|f| f.call} # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

...because i is now being declared separately for each time through. But now I get lost: why can't I also fix it by introducing an intermediate variable?

```
array = []
for i in 1..5
  j = i
  array << lambda {j}
end
array.map{|f| f.call} # => [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Because j is new each time through the loop, I'd think a different variable would be captured on each pass. For example, this is definitely how C# works, and how -- I think-- Lisp behaves with a let. But in Ruby not so much. What's really happening?

Edit: See comments in the answers; the problem seems to be that j is still in scope outside the loop. How does scope in loops really work?

Edit: I guess I still don't understand; if loops don't create new scopes, why this:

```
for i in 1..5
  puts j if i > 1 #undefined local variable or method `j' for main:Object (NameError)
  j = i
end
```

Comment: with `puts j`, j has not been assigned to anything yet. local variables need to be assigned first before you can use them (they don't autovivify.) It's just that the for loop is not creating a new scope within it, so j never falls out of scope at the end of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, this is getting ridiculous. Every time I try to answer a question about how `for` loops work in Ruby, I get it wrong.

The reason for this is, of course, that I don't use `for` loops in Ruby, neither does anybody else, so it really doesn't matter to me :-)

Anyway, to settle the matter once and for all, I went straight to [the ultimate source](http://Ruby-Std.NetLab.Jp/), the December 1, 2009 preliminary Draft of the IPA Ruby Language Specification (destined to become the ISO Ruby Language Specification):

> ## §11.4.1.2.3 The `for` expression
>
> ### Syntax
>
> - *for-expression* **→** <kbd>for</kbd> *for-variable* <kbd>in</kbd> *expression*  *do-clause* <kbd>end</kbd>
> - *for-variable* **→** *left-hand-side* **|** *multiple-left-hand-side*
>
> The *expression* of a *for-expression* shall not be a *jump-expression*.
>
> ### Semantics
>
> A *for-expression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate the *expression*. Let `O` be the resulting value.
> 2. Let `E` be the *primary-method-invocation* of the form *primary-expression* **[no line-terminator here]**<kbd>.each do |</kbd> *block-formal-argument-list* <kbd>|</kbd> *block-body* <kbd>end</kbd>, where the value of the *primary-expression* is `O`,the *block-formal-argument-list* is the *for-variable*, the *block-body* is the *compound-statement* of the *do-clause*.
>
>    Evaluate `E`, but skip Step c of §11.2.2.
> 3. The value of the *for-expression* is the resulting value of the invocation.

Okay, so basically this means that

```
for for_variable in expression
  do_clause
end
```

gets translated to

```
O = expression
O.each do |for_variable|
  do_clause
end
```

Or, in your case:

```
for i in 1..5
  puts j if i > 1 #undefined local variable or method `j' (NameError)
  j = i
end
```

gets translated to

```
(1..5).each do |i|
  puts j if i > 1 #no excpetion here, works just fine ??!!??
  j = i
end
```

Aha! But we forgot something! There's this ominous "skip Step c of §11.2.2." thing! So, what does it say?

> - Push an empty set of local variable bindings onto ⟦local-variable-bindings⟧.

Note that Step b

> - Set the execution context to `E`<sub>`b`</sub>.

is *not* skipped.

So, as far as I can see, a `for` loop gets its own execution context, which starts out as a copy of the current execution context, but it *does not* get its own set of local variable bindings. IOW: it gets its own dynamic execution context, but not its own lexical scope.

I must admit, I'm still not sure I fully understand it, but it doesn't get any more precise than this.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Ruby are you running this on? 1.8 does not have block scope for local variables, so j is still hanging around (and equal to 5) even after the end of the `for`.

Comment: 1.9.1.  When exploring this, I'd put a `puts j` above `j=i` and got an error, so I'd ruled out j's scope as the issue. But I just tried `puts j` at the very end, and it does print 5, so something is up there. So maybe the real question is, how does j's scope work here?

Comment: er, I mean `puts j if i > 1`, or else I'd get an error regardless