# Pass var value to closure on ruby

Tags: ruby, closures, vagrant

I have a Vagrantfile with this snippet:

```
  for j in 1..3
    config.vm.define "zookeeper#{j}" do |s|
      puts j
    end
    puts "#{j}"
  end
```

My aim is to set the IP according to the value of `j` on each iteration, but when Vagrant creates the virtual machine, the value is always 3 (last value of the for iteration)

This prints the following:

```
1
2
3
3 <-- should start with 1
3
3
```

How can I use the value for each iteration instead of the final value of `j`?

Comment: How many times the for loop you want to run like 123123.. so on ?

Comment: nope, just 3 iterations

Comment: may be somewhere inside the code you are resetting it `j` to 3...

Comment: Need more context I think

Comment: No, as you can see I am only printing it, I suspect the inner puts is taking reference of `j` instead of the value

Comment: Based on your answer to @ArupRakshit it is unclear what the question is... Is there an outer loop not shown? The code sample would not give the given output, just 123. By the way I suspect in Vagrant each time the block is run it overwrites the previously set configuration, in other words you can only `vm.define` once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831470/closures-and-for-loops-in-ruby), basically:

> a for loop gets its own execution context, which starts out as a copy
>   of the current execution context, but it does not get its own set of
>   local variable bindings

I have changed the for for an each, and now it works:

```
(1..3).each do |j|
    config.vm.define "zookeeper#{j}" do |s|
      puts j
    end
  end
```

Comment: That's why nobody ever uses them.

Comment: Well, this was my first contact with Ruby, I'm astonished how people does not seem to use `for` and that it has this kind of glitches

Comment: It's not a glitch. It's consistent with every other control structure in Ruby. Only script bodies, method bodies, class bodies, module bodies, lambda literal bodies and block bodies create a new lexical scope. `for` loops, `while` loops, `until` loops, `if` expressions, `unless` expressions, `begin` blocks, `case` expressions do not.