# Configure Multiple Bridge IPs in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I have the following `Vagrantfile` which defines many ([multi-machine](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/index.html)) VMs:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  for i in 1..3 do
    config.vm.define "vm#{i}" do |c|
      c.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
      c.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.#{i + 100}"
      c.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: rand(2000...4000), id: 'ssh'
    end
  end
end
```

After performing `vagrant up`, each VM has the same `eth1` interface:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:43:e7:4f
          inet addr:192.168.0.103  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2607:b400:26:0:a00:27ff:fe43:e74f/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe43:e74f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:10065 (10.0 KB)  TX bytes:3832 (3.8 KB)
```

I would like each VM to have a separate IP, but each one strangely adopts the IP `192.168.0.103`. If I omit the `ip` specification to `public_network`, each VM's `eth1` IP is different.

How can I configure multiple bridge IPs in a multi-machine `Vagrantfile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess its one of ruby caveat (you can read [Closures and for loops in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831470/closures-and-for-loops-in-ruby?rq=1) and probably other good resources on the net)

basically replace you for loop

```
for i in 1..3 do
```

with equivalent

```
(1..3).each do |i|
```