# How to add scheduler with ruby loop?

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop, scheduler

I am trying to code a `twitchbot`.
I want to add a scheduler with `for loop`.

I tried that code but it‘s just printing `!prima`.By the way, scheduler's timer `sume2` is working fine.

```
require "rufus-scheduler"

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
sume = ['!prime', 'sea', 'ase', '!prima']
sume2 = ['30s', '20s', '10s', '40s']
s3 = sume2.length - 1

for x in 0..s3
  scheduler.interval sume2[x] do 
    puts sume[x]
  end 
end
```

What can I do about that?

Comment: I think your main problem is the loop type you are going to use. It's nothing wrong with the scheduler. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is you are using a `for` loop instead of an Enumerable method such as `each`.

Short answer, just change `for x in 0..s3` to `sume2.each_index do |x|`

Longer answer, you can compare the following:

```
for x in 0..3
  Thread.new { loop { puts(x); sleep 1 } }
end
```

with:

```
(0..3).each do |x|
  Thread.new { loop { puts(x); sleep 1 } }
end
```

The first just prints `3` repeatedly, but the second prints `1,2,3` as intended

Why? It's because with the `for` loop. your `x` variable gets *overwritten* each loop. With each, your `x` variable is *scoped to the block* and you have a *closure*.

For more explanation, see [Closures and for loops in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831470/closures-and-for-loops-in-ruby), or https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-ruby-closures, or just google "closures in ruby"

Note, it's not idiomatic to use `for` loops in Ruby, for this particular reason

Comment: thx god to u wrote here it worked thx a lots of . i didnt sleep all night for that lol.